# Draw a marker like google maps with TCanvas on Delphi

Tags: delphi, gdi+, gdi, marker

On my application I need draw on TCanvas a "marker", like Google Maps marker (see the image).

[image: google marker]

I'd like use as parameters the radius, the height and the origin:

[image: marker parameters]

I don't have idea about algorithm to use. I can use an arc to draw the top, but how can I draw the bottom?
Note: I need draw it both with GDI and GDI+ so any solution is welcome.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but I don't think this got anything to do with Delphi or GDI in particular. It's more like looking for an algorithm that takes three parameters and outputs something like the above.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful it's possible but I need do it with Delphi using GDI and GDI+

Comment: The point is that once you have the mathematical description, you can draw it in whatever language you fancy. It's categorically not a delphi question. FWIW I bet google use raster images.

Comment: This has no 'inward curve' but it's a simple algoritm: http://www.how-to-draw-funny-cartoons.com/cartoon-water.html

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes a mathematical description is OK for me. I have description what I need to do but a "simple" mathematical solution of the problem is a point of start, was I wrong to indicate delphi? Yes, Google use a raster image to solve the problem.

Comment: Why not use raster image?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan bacause the user need change size and color dynamically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a quick example using a 200x200 `PaintBox` - it should at least give you an idea for the algorithm.  I trust you can draw the black dot in the middle.  Read up on [Bezier Curves](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.PolyBezier); `PolyBezier` defines [*cubic* Bezier curves. (link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Higher-order_curves)

[image: bezier]

Four points define a cubic Bezier curve - start, end, and two control points.  Control points define the strength of curvature as the line moves from start to end.

```
var origin, innerL, midL, midR, lft, tp, rgt, innerR : TPoint;
    radius, hgt : integer;
begin    
  radius := 25;
  hgt := 90;    
  origin.X := 100;
  origin.Y := 180;
  //control points
  innerL.X := origin.X;
  innerL.Y := origin.Y - (hgt - radius) div 3;
  midL.X := origin.X - radius;
  midL.Y := origin.Y - 2*((hgt - radius) div 3);
  //top circle
  lft.X := origin.X - radius;
  lft.Y := origin.Y - (hgt - radius);
  tp.X := origin.X;
  tp.Y := origin.Y - hgt;
  rgt.X := origin.X + radius;
  rgt.Y := lft.Y;
  //control points
  midR.X := origin.X + radius;
  midR.Y := midL.Y;
  innerR.X := origin.X;
  innerR.Y := innerL.Y;

  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.PolyBezier([origin, innerL, midL, lft]);
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Arc(lft.X, tp.Y, rgt.X, rgt.Y + radius, rgt.X, rgt.Y, lft.X, lft.Y);
  PaintBox1.Canvas.PolyBezier([rgt, midR, innerR, origin]);
  //fill
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FloodFill(origin.X, origin.Y - radius,
                             Canvas.Pen.Color, TFillStyle.fsBorder);    
end;
```

To satisfy the point that you can do this with one bezier :

```
  // add four more control TPoints
  cornerL.X := lft.X;
  cornerL.Y := tp.Y + radius div 2;
  cL2.X := lft.X + radius div 2;
  cL2.Y := tp.Y;
  cR2.X := rgt.X - radius div 2;
  cR2.Y := tp.Y;
  cornerR.X := rgt.X;
  cornerR.Y := cornerL.Y;


  PaintBox1.Canvas.PolyBezier([origin, innerL, midL, lft,
                               cornerL, cL2, tp, cR2, cornerR, rgt,
                               midR, innerR, origin]);
```

Comment: There's no need for ex-post `FloodFill` fill. Also, you can describe the whole marker shape by bezier curves (and draw it by a single `PolyBezier` call).

Comment: @TLama - yes, you can do it with one bezier.  I did it quickly and didn't want to define four more control points - it was meant to be didactic, not production complete.  Arc was faster to code, not necessarily better.  Obviously a GDI solution would use paths (that define Beziers in the same way) and with paths the post fill is not needed, naturally.  Again, it was a bezier how-to, not trying to do OP's job for him.

Comment: Yes, that's better :-) And, you're right. With GDI+ you can make a path and fill the path. It's easier there. [+1]

Comment: @TLama  Glad to have generated a smile :)